is there any C++ grpc server emebeded in the milvus system?
I recently found an error which should be throwed from C++ code (after searching the error text write index to fd error, errorCode is).
I know there is a HandleCStatus function that logs all the C errors in GO (as long as the C code is called in Go, any error should be logged, right?). But I cannot find any CStatus returns err logs.
How could this heppen?
im wondering if there is any C++ server in the system such that its C code is not handled by Go?
milvus: 2.3.5
